# copying data from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, file

i am trying to replace the current data in my file with the data in any another selected file which have same attributes. i want to replace the data from A1:Q in the current file from any other selected file. I tried writing the code but its showing errors .

```
Sub newdata()



Set appxl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Dim myfile As Window
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim sourceFileName As String


'Open Source File.xlsx
With appxl

    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If vFile = False Then Exit Sub  'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
   ' Set myfile = Workbooks.Open(vFile)


    .Visible = False
End With

'Get first sheet data
Set myfile = appxl.Windows(vFile)
myfile.Activate
Set currentSheet = myfile.Sheets(1)

'Past the table in my current Excel file
lastRow = currentSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Data retrieval").Range("A1:E" & lastRow) = currentSheet.Range("A1:Q" & lastRow).Value

'Close Source File.xlsx
appxl.Workbooks(vFile).Close


End Sub
```

Comment: It was shoing errors in the line Set         myfile = appxl.Windows(vFile)       but now with the new code below its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the prettiest of codes but it works just as you asked!

```
Sub newdata()

Dim myfile As Window
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim sourceFileName As String
Dim sourcefileworksheet As String
Dim destinationwb As String
Dim destinationwksheet As String
'set destination worksheet as open workbook when you run macro

destinationwb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
destinationwksheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'Select source file
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
 ' cancel macro if nothing selected
        If fNameAndPath = False Then
        MsgBox ("Nothing Selected, Macro Cancelled")
        Exit Sub
        End If

'Open Source File.xlsx
Workbooks.Open (fNameAndPath)

'set source names
sourceFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
sourcefileworksheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'Determine last row of source
lastRow = Workbooks(sourceFileName).Worksheets(sourcefileworksheet).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'Past the table in my current Excel file - Note that you should change the range of destination to A1:Q if you want all copied
Workbooks(destinationwb).Worksheets(destinationwksheet).Range("A1:E" & lastRow) = Workbooks(sourceFileName).Worksheets(sourcefileworksheet).Range("A1:Q" & lastRow).Value

'Close Source File.xlsx
Workbooks(sourceFileName).Close

'Confirm complete
MsgBox ("Complete!")

End Sub
```